# drush can't find Drupal site after migrating to PostgreSQL

Tags: windows, postgresql, drupal, drush

After migrating from `MySQL` to `Postgres` drush outputs at my Drupal project:

```
drush cc all
No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.
```

The Drupal project works without issues. Connecting to pg db from cli works also.

Command `drush sql-connect` outputs:

> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\dru4F48.tmp psql -q --dbname=xxx --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-align --field-separator='        ' --pset tuples_only=on

System: **Win 7** / **php5.4.43** / **drush 7.3** / **postgres 9.3**

When I run `drush sql-cli`, this message is displayed:

> command `PGPASSFILE` is not available

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a drushrc or drush alias file that might still define the MySQL connection information?

Comment: no, there is nothing like that but if i do >drush sql-cli i get the message, that the command "PGPASSFILE" is not available

Comment: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/880

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Remownz comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910614/drush-cant-find-drupal-site-after-migrating-to-postgresql#comment61514298_36910614), it seems got into Drush bug related to command-line syntax on Windows when passing PostgreSQL's password file (`PGPASSFILE`). Check related pull requests: [#880](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/880) and [#2973](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2973) at GitHub which are attempting to fix it. Try upgrading to Drush 8.x or higher, if won't work, apply the mentioned patches (pull requests).

Here is the link to the bug report: [#492 - Drupal 7 on WAMP with PostgreSQL](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/492).

---

Patch file content for Drush 8.x (for manual patch):

```
--- a/src/Sql/SqlPgsql.php
+++ b/src/Sql/SqlPgsql.php
@@ -41,10 +41,10 @@ private function createPasswordFile()

     public function command()
     {
-        $environment = "";
+        $environment = drush_is_windows() ? "SET " : "";
         $pw_file = $this->createPasswordFile();
         if (isset($pw_file)) {
-            $environment = "PGPASSFILE={$pw_file} ";
+            $environment .= "PGPASSFILE={$pw_file} ";
         }
         return "{$environment}psql -q";
     }
```